# Windows 10 Swipe From Right Edge

Tags: windows-10

I am working with a Windows 10 touch-enabled laptop, and it has been requested that the action center not pop out with a swipe from the right edge of the screen. Is it possible to disable that, such that the only way to access the Action Center is through its system tray icon?